# Extracting Facebook Comments With IMacros

Tags: facebook, imacros

I'm trying to extract comments from certain facebook posts and put that information into a table.

I can copy the commenter and and their comment with:

TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:UFICommentContent EXTRACT=TXT

but I'm unsure how to get this information separately to put it in a table like so: 
COMMENTER NAME | COMMENT | COMMENTER'S FACEBOOK URL

Any advice?

Comment: What does your variable !EXTRACT look like? Write down this string.

Comment: Use JS and extract the whole string.

Answer (score 0):

Use VBA to run your imacro if you're planning to store it in Excel(this feature is available only on Enterprise editions, vba integration, ie.).

All you'll need to do is create a loop with the imacro script and row iteration update inside.
Like so:

```
row=1 'choose which row to start from
Do While True
    ret = imac.iimPlay("CODE:TAG <line to extract commenter name>" & vbCrLf & _
    "TAG <line to extract comment>" & vbCrLf & "TAG <line to extract URL>")
    'Determine when to stop
    If not ret < 0 then
        Worksheets("Ur wksht").cells(row, 1).value = imac.iimGetExtract(1)
        Worksheets("Ur wksht").cells(row, 2).value = imac.iimGetExtract(2)
        Worksheets("Ur wksht").cells(row, 1).value = imac.iimGetExtract(3)
    Else
        MsgBox("All Done!")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'iterate row
    row = row + 1
Loop
```

Hope this helps.